# Having trouble insert data to table with default values

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I have a table that has 4 attributes.

```
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| url          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| mail         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| date_entered | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| active       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1                 |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Now i want to insert only the data_entered and other attributes to get default values.
I'm doing it for the id field which I need to be exact to another id I insereted to different table.

this is the code:

```
        tx.execute(\
            "insert into company_career (date_entered) "
            "values (%s)",
            (time.time())
        )
```

This is the error:

```
        query = query % db.literal(args)
    exceptions.TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How to fix it?

Comment: you need to format that string to be an acceptable date/time format.

Comment: I used the same time.time() in another table and all went fine.
so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to insert with: insert into company(url,mail,date_entered) values("","","now");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tx.execute(\
            "insert into company_career (date_entered) "
            "values (FROM_UNIXTIME('%s'))",
            (time.time())
        )
```

Comment: I did manage to insert with:
insert into company(url,mail,date_entered) values("","","now");

Answer (score 0):

when you are providing values into a insert query dont forget to enclode it in commas

```
"insert into company_career (date_entered) values ('%s')"
```